# Create/replace trigger in Squirrel

Tags: oracle, squirrel-sql

I use squirrel 3.2.0 
When I try to replace this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER crw_ins_trig
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON crew
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN
    if (:new.crw_id is null) then
        select crw_id_seq.nextval
        into :new.crw_id
        from dual;
    end if;  
END;
/
```

I get the message "Please input the parameter values.  Value for ':new'"

When I click OK the result message is:

```
Warning:   Warning: execution completed with warning
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 17110
Position: 27

Query 1 of 1, Rows read: 0, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 0.023, SQL query: 0.023, Building output: 0
```

In my application I get an error `"ORA-04098: trigger 'CRW_INS_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation"`

Does this has to do with Squirrel? If so, how can I solve this?

Comment: The problem might be the blank line between the DECLARE and BEGIN. Perhaps Squirrel is interpreting the first four lines as the CREATE TRIGGER command (resulting in an invalid trigger), then trying to execute the BEGIN-END block as an anonymous block.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should unload "sqlparam" plugin in SQuirrel, after that it won't ask you to fill values for ":paramName" variables

Comment: Yes! It works and the trigger is created and valid in Oracle!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a REFERENCING line to your trigger so that it would look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER crw_ins_trig  
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON crew  
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
              OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    if (:new.crw_id is null) then  
        select crw_id_seq.nextval  
        into :new.crw_id  
        from dual;  
    end if;    
END crw_ins_trig;
```

Try that.  If it doesn't work, try executing the statement using a different tool (e.g. SQL*Plus, PL/SQL Developer, Toad, etc).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: that does not do anything, if you want to reference new as something, you better rename it to something other then new, like n